# Как написать функцию swap для словаря?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, map

Как мне написать функцию `void* swap(Map& b);` для собственного словаря, построенного на дереве? Функции дерева реализованы. Есть структура и ключ.

```
typedef std::string Key;

struct Value {
    unsigned age;
    unsigned weight;
};
```

Comment: Что должна делать Ваша функция `swap`?

Comment: // Обменивает значения двух словарей.
  // Подумайте, зачем нужен этот метод, при наличии стандартной функции
  // std::swap.
(Комментарии преподавателя)

Comment: ответ преподавателю - либо потому, что стандартный swap не делает то, что нужно (например, оставляет дерево в неверном состоянии) либо преподаватель хочет что бы Вы написали свою.

Comment: Это я понял)как мне ее реализовать?(Хотя бы общими словами)

Comment: Понимаете, телепаты все в отпуске, Белка и Стрелка в космосе. Никто не может кроме Вас сказать, что там за код и что там должен делать эта функция.

Comment: Совершенно непонятно, почему ваша функция swap принимает один аргумент и возвращает `void*`. Опишите желаемую семантику.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: @KoVadim, очевидно же.

Comment: @VladD, 1 аргумент, потому что она член класса - this и с кем меняем - в аргументе. А вот почему `void*` - это интереснее.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Для функции, которая подменяет сам объект, быть членом класса этого самого объекта как-то очень странно. Представьте себе команду собаке — «а вот измени свою сущность на сущность другой собаки»! Моё воображение легче принимает такое, если функция по отношению к объекту внешняя. А так, чисто синтаксически, можно, конечно, что угодно.

Comment: @VladD, лучше вспомни vector, string и другие стандартные классы - к них swap является инстансным методом же. Что-то я удивлён, что для тебя это неожиданность о_О

Comment: @Qwertiy: Не то, чтобы неожиданность. Но идеологически чистым я бы это решение не назвал.

Comment: @VladD, думаю, это для краткости кода. `std::vecor<int>::swap(a, b)` vs `a.swap(b)`.

Comment: Ну, `std:vector` мог бы перегрузить `std::swap`. Точно так же, как он перегружает `operator<<(ostream& o, ...)`. Тогда выглядело бы `std::swap(a, b);` (может быть, так в реальности и происходит?).

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Берёшь по корню от каждого словаря и меняешь местами все указатели и примитивные данные, которые у тебя там есть. Для stl-типов вызываешь их swap. Для всего что осталось - std::swap. Вроде всё.

Да, а метод нужен для более эффективного обмена значений за счёт того, что учитывается внутренняя реализация объекта и без создания временных объектов меняется местами только то, что требуется.

Answer (score 1):

Фактически, как следует из вашего же собственного вопроса, все, что вам необходимо, это обменять деревья, которые реализуют ваш класс, и сопутствующие им свойства, как, например, количество элементов в дереве.

Чтобы обменять деревья, которые, как я предполагаю, создаются динамически, вам просто необходимо обменять указатели на корни этих деревьев.

Все, что вам нужно, это просто применить стандартную функцию `std::swap` к каждому нестатическому члену класса.

И конечно данное объявление функции

```
void* swap(Map& b);
```

не имеет смысла. Функции следует иметь тип возвращаемого значения `void` , а не указатель `void *`.

Вам следует, во-первых, объявить член класса функцию `swap`

```
class Map
{
    //...
    void swap( Map & );
   // ...
};
```

А также объявить общую функцию `swap` отдельно от класса как

```
void swap( Map &lhs, Map &rhs )
{
    lhs.swap( rhs );
}
```

Это будет соответствовать тому шаблону, который используется в стандарте C++ для определенных пользователем классов.

Comment: Из соображений эффективности, если есть контейнеры, реализующие собственный swap (например, vector), то надо их swap и вызывать.